# Capture everything else in string using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have to extract 3 things from a string, PO box, street address and everything else.

Here's how the string would look:

> DUNHOUR AGENCY INC         PO BOX 48                  44 TANNER STREET           HADDONFIELD    NJ 08033    VERONA         NJ 070440324

I have managed to extract PO and street address using the following regex but have been running in circles to get the remaining part of the string.

Here's what my regex is;

```
\b(PO BOX \d{2,5}|PO Box \d{2,5}|P.O. BOX \d{2,5}|P O BOX \d{2,5})?\s*(\d+\s[A-z]+\s[A-z]+)\s(\d+\s[A-z]+)?
```

How can I get everything else as last group match?

I should also be able to extract rest of the data if PO box information is missing that is

> *BENNETTI-HOLMES INSURANCE   43 VOSHELL MILL ROAD         DOVER          DE 19904

I should get false for PO, get the street address and everything else in last group match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to get it done using

```
\b(PO BOX \d{2,5}|PO Box \d{2,5}|P.O. BOX \d{2,5}|P O BOX \d{2,5})?\s*(\d+\s[A-z]+\s[A-z]+\b(\sROAD|STREET|AVENUE|DRIVE|RD|ST|AV|DR)?)\s+(.{0,100})
```

Answer (score 2):

A few minor notes about the pattern in your posted answer.

- This part `[A-z]` [matches more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret) than `[A-Za-z]`
- This part is optional `(\sROAD|STREET|AVENUE|DRIVE|RD|ST|AV|DR)?` so your pattern will also match if you leave it out
- In this part `\sROAD` the whitespace char will match only before ROAD and will not apply to the other alternatives
- Note that `\s` might also match a newline and escape the dot `\.` to match it literally

You might update the pattern to

```
\b((?:P ?O|P\.O\.) B(?:ox|OX)\s*\d{2,5})?\s*(\d+\s[A-Za-z]+(?:\s[A-Za-z]+)*\s(?:ROAD|STREET|AVENUE|DRIVE|RD|ST|AV|DR))\s(.{0,100})
```

In separate parts:

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:P ?O|P\.O\.)`  Match the variants of PO P O or P.O.
  - `B(?:ox|OX)` Match either Box or BOX
  - `\s*\d{2,5}` Match 0+ whitespace chars and 2-5 digits
- `)?` Close group 1 and make it optional
- `\s*` Match 0+ whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `\d+\s[A-Za-z]+` Match 1+ digits and 1+ chars A-Za-z
  - `(?:\s[A-Za-z]+)*` Repeat 0+ times matching a whitespace char and 1+ times A-Za-z
  - `\s(?:ROAD|STREET|AVENUE|DRIVE|RD|ST|AV|DR)` Match a whitespace char and one of the alternatives
- `)` Close group 2
- `\s` Match a whitespace char
- `(.{0,100})` Capture **group 3**, match any char except a newline 0-100 times

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%28%28%3f%3aP+%3fO%7cP%5c.O%5c.%29+B%28%3f%3aox%7cOX%29%5cs*%5cd%7b2%2c5%7d%29%3f%5cs*%28%5cd%2b%5cs%5bA-Za-z%5d%2b%28%3f%3a%5cs%5bA-Za-z%5d%2b%29*%5cs%28%3f%3aROAD%7cSTREET%7cAVENUE%7cDRIVE%7cRD%7cST%7cAV%7cDR%29%29%5cs%28.%7b0%2c100%7d%29&i=DUNHOUR+AGENCY+INC+PO+BOX+48+44+TANNER+STREET+HADDONFIELD+NJ+08033+VERONA+NJ+070440324%0d%0aDUNHOUR+AGENCY+INC+P+O+BOX+48+44+TANNER+STREET+HADDONFIELD+NJ+08033+VERONA+NJ+070440324%0d%0aDUNHOUR+AGENCY+INC+P.O.+BOX+48+44+TANNER+STREET+HADDONFIELD+NJ+08033+VERONA+NJ+070440324%0d%0aDUNHOUR+AGENCY+INC+P.O.+Box+48+44+TANNER+STREET+HADDONFIELD+NJ+08033+VERONA+NJ+070440324%0d%0a%0d%0a*BENNETTI-HOLMES+INSURANCE+43+VOSHELL+MILL+ROAD+DOVER+DE+19904%0d%0a%0d%0a)